# Unable to execute AWS API gateway url from cURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created one simple api gateway, which will trigger lambda function and returns some welcome message to the caller.

If I call api url from browser, it is working for both http (internally it is redirecting to https) and https calls.

If I call using cURL, http call is not redirecting to https and I am getting following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: CloudFront
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 11:27:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 183
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://f1234567.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/test
X-Cache: Redirect from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 werfdbdcc66044d560a313352d21.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: sfdgfgsdqr7WzN85pe0AD6565bEKZoT4x56gN24dfgdf

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<center>CloudFront</center>
</body>
</html>
```

As next step, I want to call this api url from my hardware device.

Comment: what's the curl command you fired to api gateway?

Comment: Enable logging on your API gateway and show us the error messages that appear there. Many times the API gateway will respond with a general message but will have details in the logs that will help track down such a problem

Comment: If you are trying to access `https://f1234567.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/test` and got 301 response code, add a trailing / to the url and try. So, your effective url becomes `https://f1234567.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/test/`

Answer (score 4):

It is not an error. What you're seeing is the exact behaviour you wanted -- 301 redirection. However curl does not follow redirects (unlike browsers, for instance) unless explicitly told to do so.

Adding `-L` switch to your curl call will enable redirects.

You can also enable verbosity flag `-v` and observe that it will then hit 301 before being redirected to https.

Comment: Thanks mewa! it really worked with -L command. Next I tried with my hardware [quictel cellular module] to make https call to same aws api gateway url, and it is asking for ssl certificates. Kindly do let me know, how to make call to https aws api gateway url from hardware. Commands like this;
AT+QSSLCFG=“seclevel”,1,2 //Set the SSL verify level as 2, it means you should upload CA
OK Cert, client Cert & client private key by AT+QFUPL command.
AT+QSSLCFG=“cacert”,1,“RAM:cacert.pem”
OK
AT+QSSLCFG=“clientcert”,1,“RAM:clientcert.pem”
OK
AT+QSSLCFG=“clientkey”,1,“RAM:clientkey.pem”

Comment: for those using curl in php: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`